# Specialized shoe Boa SV2 ratchet service?

Tags: shoes

I've got a pair of Specialized [Comp Mountain Bike Shoes](https://www.specialized.com/us/en/comp-mountain-bike-shoes/p/155761?color=228712-155761) that the ratchet mechanism has broken on: it comes loose when under any load.

Is the Boa SV2 dial / ratchet mechanism replaceable or serviceable, and if so what parts do I need to repair the shoe and how do I perform the repair?

Comment: Are you aware of Boa’s replacement program? https://store.boafit.com/en-us/warranty

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Boa is a company that makes closure systems for cycling and other shoes. My understanding is that many, and possibly all, Boa dials are user replaceable. The dials house the ratchet mechanism and the metal wire, and are replaced as a unit. [Boa offers a lifetime warranty](https://store.boafit.com/en-us/warranty) on their products, and the link goes to their website where you can start a warranty claim. You would select the exact model of shoe you have, so that Boa knows which model of dial to supply. They will mail you a replacement free of charge. Boa covers their dials and laces, but not anything sewn in to the shoes. I have also seen replacement dials sold on Specialized’s website, but you have to pay between US$10-20 for those. Don't bother unless you want to change colors (at the time of writing, Specialized listed S2 dials in neon yellow, orange, and pink, but I believe the OP's shoes don't use that specific S2 dial).

I had a pair of 2010 S-Works shoes with the first generation Boa dials. Those were a lot less reliable than current generations, so I have much practice replacing mine. My recollection is that Boa will mail you a packet with the appropriate dials, a small Torx driver, if applicable, and instructions on how to replace the dials. I don’t see a visible Torx screw on the S2-SV dials your shoes are specced with, so there must be another way to remove them. Perhaps you simply pry them off. My recollection is that Boa do maintain a tech support line for questions, so you could call to be sure. Your local Specialized dealer may also know how to replace the dials.

The above paragraph is a dig *only* at Boa's *first* generation of laces, which I believe was offered in 2010-2011. I believe Specialized may have been the first company to partner with Boa for cycling. The OP's experience notwithstanding, *all* subsequent generations of Boa's product are a lot more reliable.

### A digression, as usual

Before Boa emerged as a company, shoe companies might use straps with Velcro, or they might make their own proprietary ratcheting buckle systems (I believe Sidi did and still do this), or perhaps there were other companies making closure systems that shoe makers would buy or license designs from (e.g. I think Northwave use another third party dial system), or more rarely they would use laces. For the record, I actually like laces, but that’s based on subjective criteria.

By now, most shoe companies buy their closures from Boa due to the quality. In much the same fashion, many cycling jersey manufacturers buy their zippers from YKK. Boa appears to have emerged as the highest quality third party manufacturer for shoe closure systems, similar to YKK and zippers.

I believe that Sidi made their own closures for quite some time before Boa’s rise as an independent company. I recall that the replacement parts for Sidi's closures are available from dealers, but that these may not have a lifetime warranty. Designing a proprietary closure system takes time and effort, and I presume that most companies determine that the trade off isn't worth it and they just buy Boa dials. Velcro and laces are seen as less technically advanced alternatives, and laces certainly can't be adjusted on the fly. That said, Fizik offers some higher-end shoes with velcro, and Giro and to a lesser extent Specialized offer some top-end models with laces.

Comment: I have a pair of Northwave shoes and I can confirm that they do not use Boa dials, but rather something of their own/different design.